# Is it correct Inject Component in another

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want to call some functions in another Component, can I inject it in constructor of current Component?

```
import { HomeComponent} from './../home/home.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(home:HomeComponent){
    home.getSomeData()
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Well, did that code compile? Run? That would probably answer your question...

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes its compiled and succees run!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot inject 1 component in to another. You should create a service for that.

You can use [Behaviour Subject](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc) to communicate between 2 unrelated components.

See this [tutorial](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/simplest-way-to-share-data-between-two-unrelated-components-in-angular)

Comment: Do I create Behaviour Subject in service or component?

Comment: Thanks for your help :)